# Кстати о...

Tags: вводные-слова, пунктуация

Отделяется ли запятой слово "кстати" от предлога "о" в оборотах типа "кстати о погоде", "кстати о природе" и т. п.?

Comment: К своему стыду, я так и не взяла в толк, какую роль играет "кстати" в таких оборотах. С одной стороны, - классический случай указания на связь со сказанным выше, с другой - вполне можно усмотреть здесь значение "пользуясь случаем", присущее слову "кстати" как члену предложения.

Comment: Слово КСТАТИ может быть НАРЕЧИЕМ (в роли необособленного обстоятельства) с двумя значениями: 1) ВОВРЕМЯ, 2) ЗАОДНО (= пользуясь случаем), а также ВВОДНЫМ СЛОВОМ со значением КСТАТИ ГОВОРЯ (= в связи со сказанным). Вводные слова членами предложения не являются, но образуют второй план речи (оформление предложения, различные отношения и др.), тогда КСТАТИ - это попутное сообщение.

Answer (score 2):

О, солнце светит! Кстати о погоде: вечером и ночью будет -1. Это наречие со значением "к месту, пользуясь случаем"

"Теперь, кстати, о погоде". Это вводное слово, его можно убрать из предложения.Оно уточняет цель сообщения.

Comment: *А теперь, кстати, я поделюсь с вами отрепетированным экспромтом.*

Как может *кстати* гармонировать с *теперь*? Не часто ли оно ныне в речи и письме выглядит притянутым за уши под видом ловкого приёма речи?..

Comment: Вы правы, в предложении "Теперь, кстати, о погоде" слова ТЕПЕРЬ и КСТАТИ не сочетаются друг с другом: КСТАТИ - это попутное замечание (импровизация по ходу),а слово  ТЕПЕРЬ служит для основного оформления текста. Также обратим внимание на то, что нельзя сделать замену: КСТАТИ = КСТАТИ ГОВОРЯ. Тем не менее такое сочетание возможно в другой ситуации, например: "Теперь, кстати, под Новый год часто бывают оттепели".

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, но расшифруем: "Теперь, кстати, о погоде"

Comment: Для  этого  предложения  не  хватает  контекста.

Comment: А какой может быть контекст? Мне кажется, что здесь один смысл: "Теперь поговорим о погоде".